# MUI tooltips/transitions and refs when dynamically rendering child functional components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-functional-component, react-forwardref

Trying to dynamically render components in React and having issues with MUI Tooltips and Transitions.  I understand I need to pass refs down to child components, but having trouble figuring out how to in my nested functional components.

Render is called with a functional component (Component) - within Component, Tooltip or Transition are optionally rendered though functional wrapper components, then an element (Elem) is optionally rendered, then child elements are rendered through Component recursively.

Nothing I have tried has worked so far - any help on how to use refs and forward them appropriately in my case would be appreciated, thanks!

```js
root.render(
<Component />
)


export default const Component = (props) => {
//each Elem is referencing another functional component (Label, Button, Panel, etc.)
     const components = {LABEL: Label, BUTTON: Button, PANEL: Panel}; 
     const Elem = components[component.type];
     const id = props.id;
     const component = useStoreValue(id);
     const children = (component.children.map((child) => (
          <Component id={child.id} key={child.id} />
     ));

     return (
          <TooltipWrapper showTooltip={component.attributes}>
               <TransitionWrapper showTransition={component.attributes}>
                    <Elem attributes={component.attributes}>
                         {children}
                    </Elem>
               </TransitionWrapper>
          </TooltipWrapper>
               
     )
}

//Thinking a ref needs to be created/used here and somehow passed to the children
const TooltipWrapper = (props) => {
     if (props.showTooltip) {
          return (
               <Tooltip title={props.showTooltip}>
                    {props.children}
               </Tooltip>
          );
     }
     return props.children;
};

//Thinking a ref needs to be created/used here and somehow passed to the children, but this should also receive a forward ref as it can be a child of tooltip
const TransitionWrapper = (props) => {
     const attributes = props.showTransition;
     const Type = components[props.showTransition['animationtype']];
     const components = {Collapse: Collapse, Fade: Fade, Slide: Slide};

     if (props.showTransition) {
          return (
               <Type {...attributes}>
                    {props.children}
               </Type>
          );
     }
     return props.children;
};

//Example Elem - thinking this should receive a forward ref which will be set on the div element.
const Panel = (props) => {
     const attributes = props.attributes;
     return <div {...attributes}>{props.children}</div>;
};
```